# API problems with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement an API into my web page. However, for some reason none of the data is being displayed. I did a similar thing as I did with a previous API and it isn't working.

The following is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var req = $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/search?q=computer"
        });

        console.log(data);

        req.done(function (data) {
            var wrapperDiv = $("<div />", {
                "class": "wrapper"
            });

            var title = $("<h2 />", {
                text: data[0].title
            });

            wrapperDiv.append(title);

            $("body").append(wrapperDiv);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With the API is datatype for title, which is a job title, and I am trying to display the first title on the page. However, nothing is displayed and I get these error messages:

[image]

I honestly have no clue what is wrong with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You log "data" outside of "done" method scope. try like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var req = $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/search?q=computer"
        });

        req.done(function (data) {

            console.log(data);

            var wrapperDiv = $("<div />", {
                "class": "wrapper"
            });

            var title = $("<h2 />", {
                text: data[0].title
            });

            wrapperDiv.append(title);

            $("body").append(wrapperDiv);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.